# Cygwin bash concatenate variables results in $'VALUE1/VALUE2\r'

Tags: cygwin

I am creating a script in bash using CYGWIN.

This is essentially what I have:

```
#!/bin/bash

username=someuser
passwd=someuserpasswd
hostname=thehost
port=1521
sid=dbname
```

When I concatenate the variables, as in

```
LOGIN_STR=${username}/${passwd}@${hostname}:${port}/${sid}
echo "Login String = $LOGIN_STR"
```

The result is:

```
Login String = $'someuser/someuserpasswd\r@thehost:1521/dbname\r'
```

To login into sqlplus, obviously this will not work.

I've also tried `LOGIN_STR=$username/$passwd@$hostname:$port/$sid`..  Same result.

I understand this probably is related to how Windows handles carriage returns vs Unix.  What I'm not clear is what I need to do to cause this to not happen any  longer.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be sure to do this in your .bash_profile or equivalent:

```
export SHELLOPTS
set -o igncr
```

This will take care of these types of carriage-return problems inside of Cygwin.